# Does GeoLite2 provide coordinates?

Tags: perl, geoip, geoip2, geolite2, geolitecity

I'm confused, does the free GeoLite2 database provide coordinates (latitude, longitude) anymore?

I have been using GeoLite and was able to use `Geo::IP` and `->latitude` calls to get coordinates. I've looked through the documentation and grepped `GeoIP2::Database::Reader` but there are no references to coordinates. Seems like it is only available when querying Maxmind through the web API.

> Note: After careful consideration, taking into account customer
>   feedback, we have decided against removing latitude and longitude
>   coordinates from the GeoLite2 databases.

Maxmind seems to suggest it should still be there? But how is it accessible with Perl then?

Comment: can you show your code?  and say exactly how and when you got your database file?

Comment: There is no code. That's what I'm looking for. I downloaded the new file today from Maxmind's website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GeoLite2 provides latitude and longitude. With the Perl `GeoIP2` API, you should be able to access as follows:

```
my $reader = GeoIP2::Database::Reader->new(
    file    => '/path/to/database',
);
my $city = $reader->city( ip => '24.24.24.24' );
say $city->location->latitude;
say $city->location->longitude;
```

Please note these coordinates are coarse estimates. See `$city->location->accuracy_radius` for the estimated accuracy (67% confidence level) of the coordinates in *kilometers*.

Comment: Thank you, that helped me understand how all the pieces go together.

Small typo in source, should be $client instead of $reader for it to be runnable.

`my $client = GeoIP2::Database::Reader->new(`

Comment: Thanks. I fixed the typo.